# How to read BLE Advertising Packets without pairing

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to read advertising packets from BLE sensors that broadcast temperature in an advertising packet every 5 seconds. I was told by the manufacturer that packet will be a GAP Scan Response Event and that I don't have to connect to the device to read this packet.

The sensor's MAC address shows up when I run `sudo hcitool lescan`

However, when I run `sudo gatttool -I -t random -b 06:09:16:41:87:DB` this happens:

`[06:09:16:41:87:DB][LE]> connect
Attempting to connect to 06:09:16:41:87:DB
Error: connect error: Connection refused (111)`

Also when I run `sudo gatttool -b 06:09:16:41:87:DB -I` and connect, I get:
`Error: connect error: Transport endpoint is not connected (107)`

How can I read this advertising packet if I am unable to make a Bluetooth connection via gatttool?

Comment: leaving a comment so I can see if anyone can help with this. I'm interested in temperature capture too ;-) . Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you want to listen to advertising events then you shouldn't connect since advertisements are broadcast. You should just scan. If you use the debugging tools "hcitool lescan" and "sudo btmon" in a separate terminal concurrently then you should see the scan response data.

Comment: This solved my problem! Thanks! I also put the specific MAC address on the hcitool whitelist (hcitool lewladd <addr>) and ran hcitool lescan --whitelist instead so that it only showed packets for that specific device.